# error/failure importing python file/module

Tags: python, import

I'm trying to import a file in my Python code, but it's not working. I wrote the following code:

```
    # Modules
    import dog

    dog.bark()
```

and in the terminal, it wrote this: Traceback (most recent call last):                          , in 
File "c:\Users\Tochukwu\Desktop\my python\main.py", line 4, in 
dog.bark()
^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'dog' has no attribute 'bark'

can you help me with a solution to this problem?

This is what I typed in the 'dog' module:

```
    # Inside dog.py
    def bark():
        print("woof!")
```

I expected "woof!" to be displayed on the terminal

Comment: We can't offer any advice without knowing what module `dog` contains.  Why did you expect this to work?

Comment: The error is not with the import.  The line of code `import dog` executed successfully.  The problem is you expected the `dog` module to contain a function or class named `bark`, but it does not.

Comment: This is what the content of the dog module:             # Inside dog.py
def bark():
    print("woof!")

Comment: You aren't importing the module you think you are. Perhaps there's a stale pyc file that doesn't contain `bark`, or you edited `dog.py` and didn't save it before trying to execute it again.